# Input voltages on LED voltmeters/ammeters

Tags: voltage

Many available panel LED voltmeters/ammeters list input power requirements of 4.5 to 28 VDC (some even 4 to 30 VDC).

What kind of input circuitry allows a digital device to function over such a wide range of voltages? (These panel meters typically measure up to 100 V DC and/or 1, 10 or 100 A DC.)

An example of the circuit would be nice.

Comment: The voltmeter circuits probaby run on 3.3 V, so there is a small switching regulator to convert the 4 - 30 V input to 3.3 V.

Comment: @Mattman944 many use linear regulators not switching.

Answer (score 0):

Can't speak for all of them but some use a high input voltage ldo voltage regulator. Low current since 30v in 3.3v out at 100ma is still 2.7 Watts wasted in heat!

Someone took a generic volt/amp panel meter and reverse engineered the entire board including schematic https://youtu.be/UubXv_w4x5s and it used a me6203a for that.

As for the voltage or current sensing, that's done though shunt resistors and an op amp.